# Problem using 'execute immediate' in PL SQL Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am using the following code in a PL SQL procedure:

```
execute immediate 'select count(distinct item_type) into counter_variable
from items where ' || field_name || ' is not null'
```

Here,

counter_variable is declared in the declaration section of the procedure
field_name is the IN parameter to the PL SQL procedure and the values passed will be column names from the 'items' table

The error that I  get is 'Invalid SQL Statement' and I am not able to figure out the reason. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

The `into` clause is PL/SQL and not valid in an SQL statement.
Try this:

```
execute immediate 'select count(distinct item_type) 
from items where ' || field_name || ' is not null' into counter_variable
```

Comment: Don't forget: If field_name is supplied by a user it has to be checked for SQL injection.